# OMNET SDN network eroor

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, omnet++

I'm working on developing SDN network on OMNET++. However, I got error about a .INI file parameter. I'm enclosing pic of error. Can you help me to fix it?
(It is desired that only host1 sends packet to host2 on the path
 **host1 -> switch -> controller -> switch -> host2**  )

[image: reqired to enter connection adress]

[image]

[image: reqired to enter connection adress]

[image: Ini file]

[image: NED file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `omnetpp.ini` after line:

```
**.host1.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "host2"
```

add this line:

```
**.host*.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = ""
```

In this context the last line means that all hosts except `host1` will not connect.

Comment: Hello Jerzy, 
Firstly, thank you so much.. and there is another issue else..
In Omnet v5, there is a SDN switch, router... but there is no SDN controller..   Can you also tell me how to create a SDN controller on OMNET v5..

Comment: @Ahmet Tıkna This is a different question. If the current issue is solved, please close the question by accepting the answer. You can then open a new question regarding the SDN controller issue.